# Multiple generic constraints with defaults relying on each other

Tags: typescript, default-value, generic-constraints

This is my Typescript interface/class structure that I have:

```
interface IBaseOptions {
    homeUrl: string;
}

abstract class BaseApp<TOptions extends IBaseOptions = IBaseOptions> {
    constructor(
        private options: TOptions
    ) {
        // does nothing
    }
}

// -----------------------------

interface ICalls {
    getValue: () => number;
}

interface IOptions<TCalls extends ICalls = ICalls> extends IBaseOptions {
    calls: TCalls;
}

class App<TOptions extends IOptions<TCalls> = IOptions<TCalls>, TCalls extends ICalls = ICalls> extends BaseApp<TOptions> {
                                   -------- (ts2744 error here)
    constructor(options: TOptions) {
        super(options);
    }
}

class SubApp extends App {
    // whatever implementation
}
```

I would like to provide the defaults so that I don't have provide concrete types for my options and calls. The way I defined my types results in a compile error (ts2744 error).

I would also like to avoid swapping my generic types (with constraints and defaults) so that I would keep the first generic type to be options and calls second.

**Is there any way to first define generic types with contraints and afterwards set their defaults?**

You can check this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcIHkAOYwA9iFsgN4CwAUMvcgBbEC2EAqlADYBcyWYKKADmAbloBfWrTgAjAVERhkCLtnKYcAQXz4APABUCRUuQgAPSCAAm5DNjyESZZAF40mxybIA+SrQYVU0EAVwQwYigACgDAhnwhADc4SGRiJ1M+IwyyWPoASn86OPoAelLka2IIchBiMEYRPOQpGlbaUEhYRBRUAGE4Li5yamL6YQgwADVBkIg+KMLXPxAQlllocTbpGk7oeCQ0Y2csQwGhs0sIGztz4bc0O6w-CytbDwdj0yLAhEHhrJPLbtGiqdTIHT6bLeS5vOxfMhnf7PB6oBGnAxPHwAGmQmORyFe13e-QJ7lJFxeVxuyE8kMM6L8o1+wSgYQi0XSMKy6MKzJK-BC+GgUS5J3yW0CrRBYKw5AAyiFZJDCdT3ir+WUKgB3RgpCCJaDIYAsfBcCBscApZySIA)

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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) work for you?

Comment: @jcalz Basically it does even though it's a bit convoluted. Put your solution in an answer so I can accept it. And also explain why you chose to put `T` and `never` in square brackets in your conditional type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious fix, swap the order of the type parameters, doesn't work for you.  So we have to resort to less obvious fixes.  The general idea here is: if you can't set the default value to what you want, set it to a dummy value, and then later when using the type, check for the dummy value and use your originally desired default instead.  So `Foo<T=Default<U>, U=X> ... T` becomes something like `Foo<V=DefaultSigil, U=X> ... V extends DefaultSigil ? Default<U> : V`.

Here's one way to do it:

```
type OrDefault<T> = [T] extends [never] ? IOptions<ICalls> : T;

class App<O extends IOptions<C> = never, C extends ICalls = ICalls>
    extends BaseApp<OrDefault<O>> {
    constructor(options: OrDefault<O>) {
        super(options);
    }
}
```

In this case we're using `never` as the dummy default; unless someone manually specifies `never` for `O`, it's a safe value to use as a dummy.  Then `OrDefault` checks to see if its parameter is `never` or not, and returns `IOptions<ICalls>` if so.

Yes, you've noticed that `OrDefault`'s check is `[T] extends [never] ? ... : ...` instead of `T extends never ? ... : ...`.  The reason I did that is to avoid [distributing](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the conditional type across `T`.  Since `T` is a "naked type parameter", when you check it like `T extends never ? ... : ...` the compiler will try to interpret `T` as a union, split the union into members, perform the conditional, and then  unite the results back into a union.  If you pass in `never` for `T`, this will be seen as an "empty union" and the result will always be `never`.  We don't want `OrDefault<never>` to be `never`, so we don't want distributive conditional types.  The easiest workaround is to prevent the check from being a "naked" type parameter by, uh, "clothing" it in a one-tuple.  `[T]` is not broken into union constituents, and therefore `OrDefault<never>` will be `IOptions<ICalls>` as desired.

And instead of using `O` later, we use `OrDefault<O>`.  You should be able to verify that this works the way you want.  It's clunky and convoluted, but it works.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)